# undefined method `boolean_label_class=' for SimpleForm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

Attempting to run migration for my Rails app pixel_paisan is getting an error reading; NoMethodError: undefined method `boolean_label_class=' for SimpleForm:Module.  Gist for the trace at https://gist.github.com/nbarnes/9796454dc28be9792284. Source code for error-production app at https://github.com/nbarnes/pixel_paisan.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling simple_form, doesn't help.  Update entire gemset, doesn't help.  Different ruby versions via RVM, doesn't help.  Plain vanilla Rails app, created in an attempt to reproduce the bug works fine. Google doesn't know about my issue.

Does anybody know anything about this? I'm rapidly running out of angles to attack it from.

Comment: The issue appears to be on line 153 of your simple_form.rb initializer. Have you tried commenting it out? (https://github.com/nbarnes/pixel_paisan/blob/master/config/initializers/simple_form.rb#L153)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**: update your simple_form gem to 3.1.0+. You have `simple_form (3.0.2)`

Longer answer: See https://github.com/rafaelfranca/simple_form-bootstrap/issues/44 which seems to be someone who had the same issue where the answer is to upgrade to simple_form 3.1.0+ whereas your Gemfile has `simple_form (3.0.2)`